# Made UI table/PCF exportable to PDF

Tags: gosu, guidewire

Is it possible to make a PCF/Table from the UI exportable to a PDF? I thought I saw it before some where in Guidewire but I can't seem to find it anymore.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible and it works well with List Views.

I tested the below solution in Guidewire 9.0*.

Steps you should follow:

**1) Declare in your PCF a variable which refers to your list view name.**

My list view ID is "MyListView"

Variable example:

```
name = MyListView
type = java.lang.String
initialValue = "MyListView"
```

**2) To the list view toolbar, you need to add a button.**

I recommend a Checked Values Toolbar Button, because this one allows you to pick the elements (rows) that you want to print.

**3) Set the following button's action:**
gw.api.print.ListViewPrintOptionPopupAction.printListViewWithOptions(MyListView)

**Result:**

When you click on the button you can choose PDF or CSV format.

If you choose PDF format, a similar document will be generated:
[image]